# how to parse XML efficiently / smoothly?

Tags: android, xml, sax

I have an online XML like this:

http://myxml.com/list.xml

```
<rootxml>
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
<url src="sdfsdfsdfsdfs" />
and so on...
</rootxml>
```

It contains like thousands of  and I tried to use SAXParser on this one but it takes 30-40 seconds to parse the XML. It is very slow for my sample app.

Comment: use this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089291/how-to-parse-xml-in-android

Comment: Refer this Link http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/android-xml-adventure-parsing-data-with-saxparser/

Comment: you can convert xml2json using the json easily. You wouldnt want to break your head with parsing xml's.

Answer (score 0):

```
String Xmlresponse=getXmlFromUrl(url);
Document mDocument =getDomElement(Xmlresponse);
NodeList mNodeResponse = mDocument.getElementsByTagName("rootxml");

for (int i = 0; i < mNodeResponse.getLength(); i++) {

Element e = (Element) mNodeResponse.item(i);
 String url=getValue(e, "url");
}



private String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

after get xml response so get Document Element

```
//here pass String xml is your response
private Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;
}


public final static String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                    .getNextSibling()) {
                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}



public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

Comment: why should he use? Any reason

Comment: He has already mentioned that he tried SAX and taking 30-40 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you help. After spending almost 10 hours on this one, I realized that what I really wanted is the **attribute value** not the actual value of the node. By using the code suggested by Saching, I came up with the following solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){   

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            String value = e.getAttribute("src");

        }
```

And it worked. Thanks again.